# Why does yosys renumber vector ports?

Tags: yosys

My top level verilog module declares signals for the four LEDs on the myStorm ice40 board, which are labelled "LED1-LED4".

```
module top (
  output [4:1] LED
);
assign LED = 4'b1010;
endmodule
```

I use the same numbering in the .pcf file:

```
set_io LED[1] 37
set_io LED[2] 38
set_io LED[3] 39
set_io LED[4] 41
```

But in the .blif output, yosys has renumbered the signals:

```
.model top
.inputs
.outputs LED[0] LED[1] LED[2] LED[3]
...
```

so arachne-pnr complains:

```
top.pcf:4: fatal error: no port `LED[4]' in top-level module `top'
```

Does yosys expect that top level vector ports are always numbered from zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Yosys BLIF back-end was not using the hints for start offset and direction (upto/downto) stored in a Yosys Wire object for generating the single-bit net names.

This is now fixed in commit [5c2c78e2dd](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys/commit/5c2c78e2dd12a860f830dafd73fbed8edf1a3823). Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Update to latest git head of Yosys and you should get the results that you are expecting.